# Nested fields mapping not working in Orika Mapper

Tags: java, spring, orika

Find below entity classes :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="rooms")
public class RoomEntity {

    @Column(name="mr_code", length=50, nullable=false)
    private String code;

    @Column(name="mr_roomtype", nullable=false, length=50)
    private String type;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "mr__hotelId", nullable = false)
    private HotelEntity hotel;

    //getters and setters
}


 @Entity
 @Table(name="hotels")
 public class HotelEntity{

    @Column(name="mh_name", nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name="mh_description")
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "hotel", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<RoomEntity> rooms = new HashSet<>(0);

    //getters and setters
 }
```

Find below DTO class

```
 public class RoomDTO{

    private String hotelName;
    private String code;
    private String type;

    //getters and setters
}
```

I written the below mapper code to copy data from RoomEntity to RoomDTO

```
public class BeanMapper {

    private static MapperFactory mapperFactory = new   DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();

        public static RoomDTO toRoomDTO(RoomEntity roomEntity) {
        mapperFactory.classMap(RoomEntity.class, RoomDTO.class).field("hotel.name","hotelName").byDefault().register();
        MapperFacade mapper = mapperFactory.getMapperFacade();
        return mapper.map(roomEntity,RoomDTO.class);
    } 
}
```

The properties - code and type values are getting copied from RoomEntity to RoomDTO.
 
But the nested properties values(**hotel.name -> hotelName**) are not getting copied.
Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you sure the `RoomEntity` instance has a hotel? Are you getting an exception or just null `hotelName`?

Comment: Yes. Room Entity has hotel(Fetch type is also EAGER here). I am not getting any exception but hotelName is null.

Comment: Can anyone please help to resolve the issue. It has been blocking my development.